# Choregraphe Software doesn't launch

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, choregraphe

I'm trying to install the choregraphe for robotics purpose .
I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 . 
So i downloaded the choregraphe-suite-x.x-linux64-setup.run file from the official website . And then :

```
chmod +x choregraphe-suite-x.x-linux64-setup.run
sudo ./choregraphe-suite-x.x-linux64-setup.run
```

Then I followed the installation steps  , i accepted the license agreement and followed the wizard steps .
But the software does not launch ..
What is the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't vouch for backwards compatibility, but was able to get the app to launch by addressing the reported error and adding a library link:

```
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /opt/'Softbank 
Robotics'/'Choregraphe Suite 2.5'/lib/libz.so.1
```

Comment: yeah it worked for me aswell , thank you for answering though

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the error is:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "".

The culprit is this error message:

> Cannot load library /opt/nao/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/opt/nao/bin/../lib/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16))

The solution is to skip the shipped libz.so.1.2.8 in lib/ with symbolic links, like so:

```
abacus:/opt/nao/lib$ dir libz.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      9 feb.   4 11:16 libz.so -> libz.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31 feb.   4 11:15 libz.so.1 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 105032 feb.   1 16:32 libz.so.1.2.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 feb.   1 16:32 libz.so.1.old -> ./libz.so.1.2.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 feb.   1 16:32 libz.so.old -> ./libz.so.1.2.8
```

and

```
abacus:/opt/nao/lib$ dir /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 mai   23  2017 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
```

With this linking, both *Choregraphe* and *robot_settings* should start up.